# Use of typekit fonts with Spring jsp

Tags: spring, fonts, webkit

We have a developed a Spring based web app and using JSPs to render pages. It all works fine. But typekit fonts we have use them in shows Flash of Unstyled Text (or FOUT). First it render a secondary or default font and then suddenly switch to the webkit font.

- When I use them in a simple html file in the same server they are working fine.
- When I use them in a simple JSP file in the same server (in non Spring app) they are working fine.
- Other sites with webkit fonts are working fine

Seems the problem is between our Spring app and Webkit fonts.

Could it be possible that we have done something wrong in Spring app?

regards

Comment: I strongly doubt that this is a problem with spring itselfe, belive that this is a problem with exactly your (spring) application. -- But to get some us more usefull answers, you have to write down some more details, for example what exactyl does not work.

Comment: @Ralph Thanks  for your comment. Everything is working the only problem is it first shows text in a default font and then in about second switch to the typekit font (FOUT).